# Authenticate if Wordpress Post URL is authentic?

Tags: wordpress, api, posts

1) I have a wordpress site with around 2000 posts.
2) On each post, in wordpress header, there is a link for signup.
3) Clicking sign-up will take the user to another site, mentioning wordpress URL in the query-string.

On the landing site, I need to check if this (wordpress) referer URL is authentic or not. How can I achieve this ?

One way I found to achieve this is to create a new API end-point, upon calling this API, it will return me true|false or something similar result stating it's authenticity.
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

But, I prefer if I can have any Wordpress plugin that can do this.

Comment: A HTTP Refer(r)er cannot be trusted. If this is not a problem for your signup process on the other site in terms of security and the origin is just meta data, it's enough validating the HTTP Referer. Otherwise, if the signup is supposed to only work for signed in users you need to do something around either one-time passwords included in the links visible only to signed in WP users and an API end-point validating those.

Comment: @Damocles This is the reason I need to verify the authenticity of wordpress-post URL

Comment: If the other website is WP powered, you could use [nonces](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/).

Comment: Is the other site WordPress AND do you have access to the database?

Comment: @HowardE Nice question, let me clearify. My first site is wordpress and second is normal website on another domain, I need to ping from 2nd website to my 1st wordpress site to verify if the URL is it's valid post.

Comment: What kind of site is the second site?  When you say "Normal" can you elaborate? and update your question a little?